# Is there a way to do grpc bidirectional streaming application load testing to send 100req/sec to a server

Tags: grpc

I was testing a grpc bidrectional streaming application which is in below link and it is working fine.

https://github.com/melledijkstra/python-grpc-chat

Do we have any tool to trigger bidirectional streaming say 100 requests per second as we use wrk/jmeter for rest/http APIs?

I tried exposing the API (run) into rest and triggering 100 req/sec using wrk tool. Seems to be not a proper approach.

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
   def send_message(self, event):
        """
        This method is called when user enters something into the textbox
        """
        message = self.entry_message.get()
        if message is not '':
            n = chat.Note()
            n.name = self.username
            n.message = message
            print("S[{}] {}".format(n.name, n.message))
            self.conn.SendNote(n)
```

Complete code is the actual grpc chat application: https://github.com/melledijkstra/python-grpc-chat

I wanted to do a load testing of a grpc bidirectional streaming application to send 100 requests per second to a server. Is there a possible approach to it?

This is to test that my server can handle the enough load with this chat functionality.

Comment: you have a solution for this currently